# Linq join with conversion

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am doing a kind of Join in my MVC application by using LINQ as,

```
 var temp= (from enumeration in db.Enumerations
            join  cust in db.Customers on Convert.ToInt32(enumeration.Value) equals cust.lkpStatus 
            where (cust.ID==data.ID &&
                   enumeration.EnumerationTypeID.Contains("Customer.lkpStatus") )
            select enumeration).FirstOrDefault();
```

In this I have got a Problem on Join is that "enumeration.Value" is a string value and " cust.lkpStatus" is an int.

So how can be the query to do joining by using the LINQ. Please suggest some LINQ query in this scenario.

Comment: what's the exception? You should talk a little about your query.

Comment: Please do suggest me some query with this kind of join.

Comment: Please do ... ? Please do answer comments. You're waisting goodwill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`

```
join  cust in db.Customers on
   enumeration.Value equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal) cust.lkpStatus).Trim()
```